# Java or Groovy equivalent of python for loop + izip

Tags: java, python, groovy, for-loop, foreach

Does anyone know the java or groovy equivalent of a python for loop using izip?

python example:

```
for item_one, item_two in izip(list_one, list_two):
```

---

I'd like to do the same in java or groovy

Thanks

Comment: Explanation for those not familiar with Python: izip constructs a lazy iterator that fetches the next item from each iterable passed to `izip` and yields them as tuple, until any iterable is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think groovy has an equivalent to izip built in, but here is one possible implementation:

```
def izip(iters) {
    return [
        hasNext: { -> iters.every{it.hasNext()} }, 
        next: { -> iters.collect{it.next()} }, 
        remove: { -> }
    ] as Iterator
}

list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = ['a', 'b', 'c']

izip([list_one.iterator(), list_two.iterator()]).each {
    println it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent in Java would be (assuming that both the lists have same length/size)

```
Object item_one, item_two;
for (int i=0; i<list_one.length; i++)
{
    item_one = list_one.get(i);
    item_two = list_two.get(i);
}
```

i.e., you will have to iterate simultaneously over the lists. This is just one example, it can be done with iterators as well.

Comment: The groovy equivalent of this one is list_one.eachWithIndex {one, i -> two = list_two[i]; }

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear...I knew that but wanted something better.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [FunctionalJava](http://www.functionaljava.org/)'s [Zipper](https://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Zipper.html):

> Provides a pointed stream, which is a non-empty zipper-like stream
>   structure that tracks an index (focus) position in a stream. Focus can
>   be moved forward and backwards through the stream, elements can be
>   inserted before or after the focused position, and the focused item
>   can be deleted.